# Where to find a complete overview for ISO P&ID standards?

Tags: standards, pi-diagram, international

I have tons of questions in regard to what is, and isn't, in accordance with ISO standards when drawing P&IDs. So, I'm looking for a resource which gives a complete overview of the standards.

---

**Meta:**

I realize this question may veer towards being off-topic, but user *RickSupportsMonica*'s answer to [this meta question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/the-engineering-se-position-on-recommendation-finding-stuff-questions?newreg=7c471965a578494fb830845485bedb53) argues questions asking for standards ought to be allowed. I agree. This isn't me asking for your opinion about what's the best resource. I'm asking for a resource that satisfies two objective, decidable criteria:

1. The resource contains ISO standards.
2. The resource is complete (that is, all standards are included).

Furthermore, the issue of ephemerality is removed if the resource is a reguarly updated site. And, it definitely isn't something that is only going to help a small number of people, given this is a basic thing that helps anyone drawing P&IDs in accordance with ISO standards. So, the only issue left is the fact that this is answerable by a simple link, though to me, that isn't really a problem. I understand if the majority of users here find it a problem though, and thus decide to close my question.

Comment: The resource you seek may be the internet.  Issue is your need for completeness.  As you argue something, so too do others, and standards change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically the text of the standard is available at:

iso.org

Though ISO has a number of local distributors, that may be more convenient to deal with or even get free acces through university libraries or physically at their library. So for example I use SFS online because thats the distributor of my local standards as well as ISO standards and my organisation has a contract with them.

Comment: Exactly what is the standard called? What is it enumerated? I have a vague memory of it being 9001, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user110391 there are several. 9001 relate to company quality systems so definitely not that. In all honesty you asked where to find the relevant standards. Thing is iso has neat categorisation of the standards so if you drill down you will find several relevant standards.

Comment: @user110391 your probably looking to start of with **ISO 15519** ([See here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:15519:-2:ed-1:v1:en)) But ist not part of the ones that I have access to so i can not verify.